# Use result that composition of analytic functions is harmonic to find harmonic conjugate of $e^{-2xy}\sin (x^{2}-y^{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions, analyticity

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719710/show-composition-of-harmonic-function-and-analytic-function-is-harmonic-without/1719785) result, I need to find a harmonic conjugate for $e^{-2xy}\sin(x^{2}-y^{2})$.

In that result, I'm supposing that $s = e^{-2xy}$ and $t = \sin(x^{2}-y^{2})$, but I really don't know how to use it to figure out anything else, and I'm starting to panic. Please help me figure out what I'm supposed to do!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: What analytic function has real part $e^u\cos v$ and imaginary part $e^u\sin v$ (if $z=u+iv$)?

Comment: yup, figured it out. You awesome!